# Error in for loop in python.. loop not working properly

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to fetch all records of JSON so I tried to do the following but for the single request, it works perfectly but when I put in the loop it shows Expected an indented block error

```
import requests

url = "https://www.example.com/web/api/Profile/info"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US"
    }

n = 10
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n):

payload = "user_id=1"


response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text+",")
sum = sum + i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the indentation in the for loop, as suggested in the traceback;

```
import requests

url = "https://www.example.com/web/api/Profile/info"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US"
    }

n = 10
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n):
    payload = "user_id={}".format(i+1)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(response.text+",")
    sum = sum + i
```

Comment: but how to loop payload?

Comment: Aye Ayee Flash!

Comment: Quick on the guns ;)

Comment: @Amitkumar you've hardcoded `payload` so it will always be the same, how do you *want* to loop over it?

Comment: @MattB. yes I want to loop it to fetch all 10 records

Comment: @MattB. I want to loop it...

Comment: @Amitkumar updated the answer.

Comment: I did with payload = "user_id=%d" %sum

Comment: Just be aware that, with your method, the first call will be `user_id=0`.